# Cannot refresh ListView in Android Contacts

Tags: android, listview, contacts

I have added a new setting to the Android 4.0.4 Contacts source, it's called useCompactView. What it does is reduce the size of the contact photos so you can fit twice as many contacts on the screen in list view.

```
<CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="useCompactView"
        android:defaultValue = "false"
        android:title="@string/display_options_use_compact_view"
        android:summary="@string/display_options_use_compact_view_summary" />
```

In ContactsPreferenceActivity I added a listener for my new checkbox and this does get fired off, I tested with a Log.d message. I tried to get the listview and call invalidateViews() on it but that doesn't work either. I am sure there has to be a way to get the adapter and force a refresh on it.

```
sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
sharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(new OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        if("useCompactView".equals(key)) {
            getListView().invalidateViews();  // This does not work
        }
    }
});
```

What I am trying to accomplish is; when the user selects Use compact view in settings, the display will be refreshed automatically. Basically I need to redraw the screen. If I go into settings, check Use compact, then also change the sort order, I get the compact view when I hit the back button. So changing the sort order does refresh the display/listview. But I don't know how to do this from my preference activity.

If you need more code, please tell me and I will put whatever you need. This is a real head scratcher.